# Drools syntax error 'mismatched input '.' in rule'

Tags: drools

I am new to drools and am receiving an error on the second line of the when clause

```
rule "grievancesMap_10"
    when
        $grievances:GrievanceDTO($grievances.getCategory().equals("NA"))
        $grievances.getSubcategory().equals("Access/Availability")
        $grievances.getSubIssue().equals("NA")
        $grievances.getIssueReason().equals("NA")
        $grievances.getProviderAccessType().equals("NA")
        $grievances.getSubcareType().equals("NA")
    then
        $grievances.setServiceType("Timely Access");
end
```

> mismatched input '.' in rule

Comment: Well you're not following drools syntax at all. I suggest reading the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading the Drools documentation. It's fantastic and covers all topics in depth.

The reason your rule is throwing errors is because your syntax is completely wrong.

```
rule "grievancesMap_10"
when
  $grievances: GrievanceDTO( category == "NA",
                             subcategory == "Access/Availability",
                             subIssue == "NA",
                             issueReason == "NA",
                             providerAccessType == "NA",
                             subcareType == "NA")
then
  $grievances.setServiceType("Timely Access");
end
```

Comment: The syntax was generated using a decision table and the jBPM workbench

Comment: You mentioned neither of those things in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have another question related to drools syntax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70060458/drools-how-to-loop-through-a-list-to-check-if-an-item-is-a-memberof-another-li